# Linked list, removing nodes from front?

Tags: c, linked-list

```
    struct node{
      char * title;
      char * type;
      struct node * next;
    };

typedef struct node headPtr;

headPtr * removeFromFront(headPtr * List){
 if(List->next==NULL){             
     return NULL;
 }
 else {
     List=List->next;
     return List;
 }
 }
```

Here is my struct and my linked list function for removing the first element in front but I can't figure out why it isn't working. It doesn't return what I want it to.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The code could be simplified as this.

```
headPtr * removeFromFront(headPtr * List)
{
    if(List == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return List->next;
}
```

However, it seemed fine, so there may be a problem on caller side

Comment: Thanks for correcting me before. I was wondering, this isn't the same as his code actually. This one may work better. In his code he was returning `List` modified, which is a local variable. Isn't this undefined behavior?

Comment: Nop, he's returning the address contained in local variable, which is valid (malloc work the same way). If an array is allocated in the function (`int array[10];`) and you return its address however, you're right, it becomes an undefined behavior.

Comment: That should be `if (List == NULL) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
headPtr * removeFromFront(headPtr * List){
 if(List != NULL && List->next != NULL){             
     headPtr *newHead = List->next;
     free(List);
     return newHead;
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, it is better to include an explanation of what it does, and why this solution is the best one for the question. Code-only answers get flagged into the Low Quality Posts review queue, and may be deleted.

Comment: Please explain why this code works.  This discourages copying and pasting without understanding the ramifications behind your choices in the algorithm.  The OP should be able to decide whether or not this code is suitable for his or her purposes.

Comment: Is it relevant at this point? The question was posted in march last year. Remove it if you want to.